# Fix Well Analysis

Tags: python, excel, debugging, analysis

So, I'm currently stuck with a bug.

I'm working with a huge dataset that contains the following information:

Information about multiple instances of many wells, each labeled with its own unique well ID number, radium contamination level, and the date that a sample was taken.

For example:

```
Well ID: AT091
Radium Level: 44.9
Sample Date: 3/18/2015

Well ID: AT091
Radium Level: 50.2
Sample Date: 2/18/2015

Well ID: AT091
Radium Level: 33.7 PCI/L
Sample Date: 7/28/2020
```

I have been asked to write a Python script that filters out data from the original dataset and creates a new Excel sheet based on the following conditions:

For each well, if the well has been sampled once per year, keep it.
For each well, if the well has been sampled multiple times in a year, keep the sample date that has the highest contamination level.

For example, if a well was sampled three times:

```
Well ID: AT091
Radium Level: 44.9
Sample Date: 3/18/2015

Well ID: AT091
Radium Level: 50.2
Sample Date: 2/18/2015

Well ID: AT091
Radium Level: 33.7 PCI/L
Sample Date: 7/28/2020
```

The code should update the spreadsheet with the following:

```
Well ID: AT091
Radium Level: 50.2
Sample Date: 2/18/2015

Well ID: AT091
Radium Level: 33.7 PCI/L
Sample Date: 7/28/2020
```

Here is the code that I have written:

```
def wells_sampled_once_per_year(well_numbers, formatted_dates, concentration):
    well_count = {}
    max_contamination = {}

    for well, date, conc in zip(well_numbers, formatted_dates, concentration):
        if date is None:
            continue
        try:
            year = pd.to_datetime(date).year
        except AttributeError:
            continue
        well_year = (well, year)
        if well_year in well_count:
            well_count[well_year] += 1
            max_contamination[well_year] = max(max_contamination[well_year], conc)
        else:
            well_count[well_year] = 1
            max_contamination[well_year] = conc

    sampled_once_per_year = [
        (well, date, conc, max_contamination[(well, pd.to_datetime(date).year)])
        for well, date, conc in zip(well_numbers, formatted_dates, concentration)
        if well_count[(well, pd.to_datetime(date).year)] == 1
    ]
    return sorted(sampled_once_per_year)

def wells_sampled_multiple_times_per_year(well_numbers, formatted_dates, concentration):
    well_count = {}
    max_contamination = {}
    
    for well, date, conc in zip(well_numbers, formatted_dates, concentration):
        if date is None:
            continue
        try:
            year = pd.to_datetime(date).year
        except AttributeError:
            continue
        well_year = (well, year)
        if well_year in well_count:
            well_count[well_year] += 1
            if conc > max_contamination[well_year]:
                max_contamination[well_year] = conc
        else:
            well_count[well_year] = 1
            max_contamination[well_year] = conc
    
    sampled_multiple_times_per_year = [
        (well, date, conc, max_contamination[(well, pd.to_datetime(date).year)])
        for well, date, conc in zip(well_numbers, formatted_dates, concentration)
        if well_count[(well, pd.to_datetime(date).year)] > 1 and conc == max_contamination[(well, pd.to_datetime(date).year)]
    ]
    
    # Remove duplicates from the list
    sampled_multiple_times_per_year = list(set(sampled_multiple_times_per_year))
    
    return sorted(sampled_multiple_times_per_year)
```

Comment: You don't tell what the _bug_ is. By the way, the consideration _if the well has been sampled once per year_ is redundant - that's only a special case of _the well has been sampled multiple times in a year_.

Comment: Sorry, but I was hoping that my explanation would be enough. The bug is with the output when considering the list of wells being sampled multiple times per year. The output should drop the remaining times that, that specific well was being sampled during that year if that sample was not the max contamination recorded for that well in that year.

Answer (score 0):

After the `for` loop, `max_contamination` contains almost all needed information, except for the date. I'd add that within the loop in order to simplify construction of the return value, i. e. change the last five lines of the loop to

```
        …
            if conc > max_contamination[well_year][1]:  # [1]: conc
                max_contamination[well_year] = (date, conc)
        else:
            well_count[well_year] = 1
            max_contamination[well_year] = (date, conc)
    return [(well, date, conc) for (well, _), (date, conc) in max_contamination.items()]
```

(or sorted, if desired).